# jQuery .next() is choosing all and not only the very next

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and have been working on a quiz with a progress indicator and ran into some problems with jQuery.
Here's my html for the progress indicator

```
<div id="progressKeeper">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="step" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

With css, I add a background image with a grey circle to all of the anchor tags with the class of `.step` and I have created one with the anchor tags with a class of `.step` and `.green` to switch the background image to a green circle

```
#progressKeeper li a.step {
    background: url(img/Progress_grey.png) no-repeat;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    position: absolute;
}

#progressKeeper li a.step.green {
    background: url(img/Progress_green.png) no-repeat;
}
```

and with jQuery, I'm trying to add the class `.green` to the very next `#progressKeeper li a.step` when the button with the class of `.btnNext` is clicked.

```
$('.btnStart').click(function(){
        $('#progressKeeper li a.step').first().addClass('green');
    });

    $('.btnNext').click(function(){
       $('#progressKeeper ul li a.step').parent().next('li').find('a').addClass('green');
});
```

My problem is that when I click on the button "Next", all of the next `li a` elements is being added the class of green. I'm using .next() and as far as I know, it should only select the first immediate sibling.

Where did I do it wrong?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I'd like the former elements in the progress to remain green. All your solutions works and thanks for your explanation but I am not sure which answer to accept since AfghanWiz' answer was the correct one, even though You didn't know exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your 'next' button is selecting all `.step` elements and then traversing to find the `a` element within each of them. You need to select only the `.step` element which also has the `.green` class, then remove `green` from that and add it to the next one. Something like this:

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
    $('#progressKeeper ul li a.step.green').removeClass('green').closest('li').next().find('a').addClass('green');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ah5ngktb/)

If you want the `green` class to progress down the list without removing from the previous item, remove the `.removeClass('green')` call: http://jsfiddle.net/ah5ngktb/1/

Comment: Good show, adding the jsfiddle. Good for testing, which is why I found that, if you `start`, `next`, `next`, `start`, you end up with multiple greens. Probably `start` should clear all greens before setting the first to green: `$('#progressKeeper ul li a.step.green').removeClass('green')`. But I still gave you one since that's _another_ question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue that comes up with people's understanding of how jQuery sets work.

This code:

```
$('#progressKeeper ul li a.step').parent()
```

...will result in a jQuery set containing **all** of the `li` elements that are parents of `a.step` elements that are inside a `ul` inside `#progressKeeper`. And so adding `.next()` after it results in a set with all but one of those `li` elements (the first one won't be in the set), because it gets the next element after **each** element currently in the set.

To limit yourself to a specific element, you can probably use your `green` class, e.g.:

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
    $('#progressKeeper ul li a.step.green').last().parent().next('li').find('a').addClass('green');
});
```

That will keep adding the class `green` after the last element that has it.

Answer (score 0):

This must point to the next first `li` and its containing `a`

```
$('.btnNext').click(function(){
       $('#progressKeeper ul li a.step.green').removeClass('green').closest('li')
           .next('li').find('a').addClass('green');
});
```